# strtolower on passing a session to a variable, is that legal?

Tags: php

Is it alright to do this?

```
$author = strtolower($_SESSION['valid_username']);
```

I want to enter all authors into the table as lower case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's fine as long as `$_SESSION['valid_username']` is set, otherwise you'll get a notice (if your error reporting is set that low).

You can check if it exists with `if (isset($_SESSION['valid_username']))`

Comment: Like this?

if(isset($_SESSION['valid_username']))
  $author = strtolower($_SESSION['valid_username']);

Comment: Yup... then you probably want something like   else $author = '';

Comment: or  something like else throw new Exception('Error: Username is not set!')

Answer (score 2):

yes.

```
$_SESSION['valid_username']
```

is a session variable which evaluates to a string so passing it as a parameter to the strtolower function is not a problem.